# VBScript - Select multiple xml nodes that use a self-closing tag

Tags: xml, dom, vbscript, nodes

I know that in vbscript we can use documentElement.SelectNodes() to select multiple xml nodes such as in the following example,

```
<Vocabulary> 
 <Word type="noun" level="1"> 
  <English>cat</English> 
  <Spanish>gato</Spanish> 
 </Word> 
 <Word type="verb" level="1"> 
  <English>speak</English> 
  <Spanish>hablar</Spanish> 
 </Word> 
 <Word type="adj" level="1"> 
  <English>big</English> 
  <Spanish>grande</Spanish> 
 </Word> 
</Vocabulary>
```

Using:

```
Set NodeList = objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("Word/English")
```

But how can the same be done for nodes without a closing tag that instead use a self-closing bracket:

```
<Vocabulary> 
 <Word type="adj" level="1"> 
  <English Text="big" />
  <Spanish Text="grande" />
 </Word> 
</Vocabulary>
```

Basically I need to get an array of nodes like this, and loop through getting the attribute value 'Text', for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly , same thing.
Think of the **objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("Word/English")(*`index`*)** such as your array.
An example prints the `Text` attributes:

```vb
Set NodeList = objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("Word/English")
For i = 0 To NodeList.length - 1
    WScript.Echo NodeList(i).getAttribute("Text")
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

**A few other XPath queries:**

```
<!-- based on this XML -->
<Vocabulary> 
  <Word type="adj" level="1"> 
    <English Text="big" /><!-- let's change this to "large" -->
    <Spanish Text="grande" />
  </Word> 
</Vocabulary>
```

**1. Select all attributes called `Text`**

```
Set xmlNodes = xmlDoc.selectNodes("//@Text")

For Each xmlNode in xmlNodes
  If xmlNode.Text = "big" Then
    xmlNode.Text = "large"
    bNodeModified = true
  End If
Next
```

**2. Select nodes that contain the attribute `Text`**

```
Set xmlNodes = xmlDoc.selectNodes("(MySelections/MySelection[@Text])")

For Each xmlNode in xmlNodes
  If xmlNode.getAttribute("Text") = "big" Then
    xmlNode.setAttribute "Text", "large"
  End If
Next
```

**3. Select nodes that contain the attribute `Text` *AND* the value `big`**

```
Set xmlNodes = xmlDoc.selectNodes("(MySelections/MySelection[@Text='big'])")

For Each xmlNode in xmlNodes
  xmlNode.setAttribute "Text", "large"
Next
```

**Whole program:**

```
Dim xmlDoc, xmlNodes, xmlNode, bNodeModified

Set xmlDoc =  CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

xmlDoc.Async = false
xmlDoc.Load "C:\MyFile.xml"

Set xmlNodes = xmlDoc.selectNodes("//@Text")

bNodeModified = false

For Each xmlNode in xmlNodes
  If xmlNode.Text = "big" Then
    xmlNode.Text = "large"
    bNodeModified = true
  End If
Next

If bNodeModified Then
  xmlDoc.Save strXmlFile
End If
```

Comment: please correct *xmlDoc.Async = "False"* and *xmlDoc.Load("C:\MyFile.xml")
*

Comment: .Async needs Boolean (False), not a string ("False"); .Load is called as a Sub, so the () are bogus.